# Symfony2 Security login AdvancedUserInterface bad credentials

Tags: php, security, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm struggling trying to make authentication work after having followed the Symfony2 documentation. I always get bad credential on every attempt to login in. I've looked around and found several cases that were due to a short password or salt field length in the database. That is not my case since i'm creating fields with 250 characters length. Here's what i get from logs

```
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT i0_.id AS id0, i0_.username AS username1, i0_.email AS email2, i0_.password AS password3, i0_.salt AS salt4, i0_.is_active AS is_active5, i1_.id AS id6, i1_.name AS name7, i1_.role AS role8 FROM iw_users i0_ LEFT JOIN user_userroles u2_ ON i0_.id = u2_.user_id LEFT JOIN iw_user_roles i1_ ON i1_.id = u2_.userroles_id WHERE i0_.username = ? OR i0_.email = ? ["test2","test2"] []
```

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Iw\SecurityBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha512
        encode_as_base64: true
        iterations:       1
    # Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: IwSecurityBundle:User }

firewalls:
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        http_basic: ~
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

login action

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the login error if there is one
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
        );
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {

        $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = '';
    }

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

    return $this->render(
        'IwSecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}
```

User entity

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserRoles", inversedBy="users")
 *
 */
private $roles;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = true;
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

User repository

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, r')
        ->leftJoin('u.roles', 'r')
        ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery();

    try {
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active admin AcmeUserBundle:User object identified by "%s".', $username), 0, $e);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

And the form registration service

```
public function formRegisterAccount($formData, $role = "ROLE_USER") {
    $newUser = new Entity\User;
    $userRoles = $this->em->getRepository('IwSecurityBundle:UserRoles')->findOneBy(array('role' => $role));
    // $encoder = $this -> factory -> getEncoder($newUser);

    if (count($this->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($formData->getUsername(), $formData->getEmail())) > 0) {
        return;
    }

    //Password encoding
    $encoder = $this->factory->getEncoder($newUser);

    $newUser->setUserName($formData->getUsername());
    $newUser->setEmail($formData->getEmail());
    $newUser->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($formData->getPassword(), $formData->getSalt()));
    // $newUser->setIsActive(FALSE);
    $newUser->addRole($userRoles);

    $this->em->persist($newUser);
    $this->em->flush();
    return $newUser;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I see that you have answered your own question. Could you perhaps remove the answer from the question itself, and post it as an actual answer (you can answer your own questions, and accept your own answers)? This way, other people can see that you have fixed the problem yourself. Right now it's not instantly clear that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it solved! I've used the encoderFactory in my service and registration is now working

service.yml

```
security_service:
    class: Iwooli\SecurityBundle\Service\SecurityService
    arguments: [@security.encoder_factory]
```

SecurityService

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory;

class SecurityService {

private $factory;

public function __construct(EncoderFactory $encoderFactory) {
    $this->factory = $encoderFactory;
}

public function formRegisterAccount($formData, $role = "ROLE_USER") {
    $newUser = new Entity\User;

    //Password encoding
    $encoder = $this->factory->getEncoder($newUser);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword($formData->getPassword(), $newUser->getSalt());
    ...
    $newUser->setPassword($password);
    ...

    return $newUser;
}
}
```

Hope that helps